# Adding Values of two elements of xml with same root

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm using xslt in order to import my xml files into InDesign and am trying to add two elements that are located on separate lines but have the same root, but a quantifier within the root that creates two separate lines.  See below, I am trying to add the two values of "Corners" into one value.

```
<sogame source="TAS For Soccer" version="1.16.01" generated="9/4/2016">
  <venue gameid="LCFH0904" visid="LC" visname="Limestone" homeid="MERW" homename="Mercy" date="9/4/2016" location="Dobbs Ferry, N.Y." stadium="Mercy Field" start="3 p.m." end="4:29 pm" duration="1:29" attend="59" schednote="" weather="75 degrees, sunny, windy" leaguegame="Y" neutralgame="N">
    <officials>
      <official title="Referee" name="Lesley Loeb" />
      <official title="Asst. Referee" name="Nora Boyer" />
      <official title="Scorer" name="Kyle Goodhart" />
    </officials>
    <rules prds="2" minutes="35" minutesot="10" />
    <show sog="1" goaldesc="1" offsides="1" fouls="0" fhk="0" />
  </venue>
  <stars />
  <status period="2" clock="70:00" />
  <team vh="V" id="LC" name="Limestone" code="1174" record="0-2, 0-1 ECAC" rank="10">
    <linescore periods="2" line="0,0" score="0" shotline="10,10" shots="20">
      <lineprd prd="1" score="0" shots="10" saves="2" fouls="0" corners="8" offsides="0" />
      <lineprd prd="2" score="0" shots="10" saves="1" fouls="0" corners="19" offsides="0" />
    </linescore>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve], so that we can see the context. In general, you would do `sum(lineprd/@corners)` from the context of `linescore`.

Comment: Yes, aside from the fact that you haven't asked a question, please post your existing XSLT code, your expected output, and your actual output. Also clarify which root and what quantifier you're referring to.

Comment: Sorry for not posting the proper formatting since this is my first post.  The first answer got me where I needed to be so thank you.